# Navigation not update map

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i using this commend

> roslaunch turtlebot3_slam
> turtlebot3_slam.launch

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

moving the robot will update the map

but i using this commend

> roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation
> turtlebot3_navigation.launch

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

i change the base_scan  to my laser, but i don't know why still here
The robot move to the target , map not update
Anyone can tall what i am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392162/navigation-not-update-map/) by [alanotmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/90204/alanotmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2021-12-03**:
By reading documentation for [SLAM launcher](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_slam/launch/turtlebot3_slam.launch) and for [navigation launcher](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_navigation/launch/turtlebot3_navigation.launch) you can see, that only the first one launches SLAM. Second one only navigates TB3 on the map. As I understood, you want to have SLAM and navigation at the same time, right?

**Comment by [alanotmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/90204/alanotmt/) on 2021-12-05**:
very close, but I mean when the robot turns around and the lidar will follow the robot turns. The lidar will not match the map. However, thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SLAM is mapping here. And navigation is localization within a known (static) map. It does what it should do. You could take a look at [slam_toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox) its an alternative to gmapping (used in your turlebot example), with many more features. It can expand/refine the map in multiple sessions, though I dont know if it can be done during localization.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2021-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alanotmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/90204/alanotmt/) on 2021-12-05**:
Thank you for your the detail. I found my real problem is the robot moves in real, but the robot model is static and the direction keep from the north.